# Disable Submit button if the form fields' values have not changed in Vue/Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

My question is simple. I have a form where a user can edit the entry in a Nuxt/Vue app. Now I want to disable the submit button until the form field's values have not changed. I use Vuex store to get the entry.

```js
// store/users.js

export const state = () => ({
  currentCustomer: null,
})

export const actions = {
  async fetchCustomer({ commit }, customerId) {
    const customer = await this.$strapi.$customers.findOne(customerId)
    commit('setCurrentCustomer', customer)
  }
}

export const mutations = {
  setCurrentCustomer(state, customer) {
    state.currentCustomer = customer
  },
}
```

Here is my Vue/Nuxt Template:

```
<template>
    <section class="d-flex flex-column mb-5">
      <b-form v-else class="border rounded bg-white p-4 shadow-sm" @submit.stop.prevent="saveUser">
        <b-form-group class="capital" label-for="name">
          <template v-slot:label> Name <span class="text-danger">*</span> </template>
          <b-form-input id="name" v-model.trim="form.name" type="text" autofocus required></b-form-input>
        </b-form-group>

        <b-form-group class="capital" label-for="email">
          <template v-slot:label> Email <span class="text-danger">*</span> </template>
          <b-form-input id="email" v-model.trim="form.email" type="email" required></b-form-input>
        </b-form-group>

        <p>Changed: {{ changed }}</p>

        <code>Actual: {{ actual }}</code>

        <code>Form: {{ form }}</code>

        <b-row>
          <b-col>
            <button type="submit" :disabled="!changed">Save</button>
          </b-col>
        </b-row>
      </b-form>
    </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      changed: false,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    form() {
      return this.$store.state.users.currentCustomer
    },
    actual() {
      return this.$store.state.users.currentCustomer
    },
  },
  watch: {
    form(newValue) {
      this.changed = newValue !== this.actual
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('users/fetchCustomer', this.$route.params.id)
  },
}
</script>
```

The above code is not working. I know that something needs to be **watched** but I can't get my head around this issue. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: why you need it?

Comment: and why you cannot simply register a onchange event listener? (is it a vue.js limitation?)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Comment: I need it because it is a better UX practice to let a user know whether he has made any change ore not. Can you please explain how onchange event can help to achieve this?

Comment: you receive onchange event, then set `changed` to true.

Comment: imho it's not a better UX if I cannot click a button just because it does nothing. Maybe show a notice and let users know they don't actually change anything?

Comment: It is the same thing.

Comment: (continue my previous comment) just like I can save my document (say, using notepad) any time, the application would not *prevent* me from doing so.

Comment: @ RavgeetDhillon what is the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for object value, add a `deep` in watch, also, you need `lodash.isEqual()` to compare if two objects are equal

```
import _ from 'lodash';

...
    watch: {
      form: {
        handler(value){
          if(value) {
            this.changed = !_.isEqual(value, this.actual);
          }
        },
        deep: true,
      }
    },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **@change="onChangeFn"** or **v-on:change="onChangeFn"** on

```
methods: {
  onChangeFn () {
    this.changed = true
  }
}
```

Comment: What if a user changes a field value and then reverts back the change. This doesn't handle that usecase.